# CSS: having trouble with the CSS display property?

Tags: css

http://elastichosts.darkgreener.com/cloud-support/index.html

Please could anyone explain why the table (`#support-table`) is being pushed down to align with 'Submit a ticket', rather than following straight on from the first paragraph?

I don't understand why the table is being pushed down, but the header and paragraph are displaying just fine inline alongside the right-hand gray block.

I assume it must be something to do with the display property of the table - I've tried setting it to `display:inline`, but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `float: left` in `extra.css` line 135. Remove that or change it to `float: none` and it scoots up to the paragraph.

Comment: THANK YOU. Why is that the case, incidentally? It was still displaying alongside a right-hand block (`div.right-box`), just not the one above (`div.right-box-support`) - why was it happy to be alongside the first but not the second?

Comment: I noticed that too... my best guess is that maybe since the top float-right box had the paragraph beside it, it was "blocked" on the left side, whereas the second float-right box had only empty space beside it. Can't say for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

You're unnecessarily floating your table left. (`float:left;`)

Removing this property will restore the table to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers pointed out, you have the float: left.  The reason that this was causing problems is because of the clear:right that you have on the button to the right.  The button is cleared to the right and the flow of the document continues fromt that point and so the table is floated to the left even with that button.